# Angular - Update a service's property from a component

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection, error-handling, custom-error-handling

I've got a service with an `appName` property. When my component does a POST, I'm trying to pass the component's name to the service's `appName` property, thus updating it in the Service, so that when the service calls this property later, it has the new value I sent from the component.

However, I can't get the service's `appName` property to update - it stays the same as initially defined in the service:

**error-logger.service.ts**

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 

  };

    appName = "initialName";

//logError function fires on error from GlobalErrorHandlerService, logging errors and passing the new appName value from component.
    logError() {
    //below should log the new appName (from component), not the initial
    console.log("Application:" + this.appName);
    }
```

}

**my-component.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ErrorLoggerService } from '../../../core/services/error-logger.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

...

  constructor(
    private errorLoggerService: ErrorLoggerService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
    ) {
      console.log("COMPONENT NAME: " + this.route.component.name);
    }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.errorLoggerService.appName = "NewAppName";
    this.errorLoggerService.postData(JSON.stringify(myData))
    .subscribe(
      data => console.warn(data),
      error => {throw error},
      () => console.log("empty")
    );
  }
```

**global-error-handler.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {ErrorLoggerService} from '../services/error-logger.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

// Global error handler for logging errors
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService extends ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private injector : Injector) {


        super();
    }

    handleError(error: any) {
      let loggerService = this.injector.get(ErrorLoggerService);
      loggerService.logError(error)    
      .subscribe(
        data => console.warn(data),
        error => {throw error},
        () => console.log("empty")
      );

  }
}
```

How can I properly update the service's property from the component? Either I've got something fundamentally wrong, or maybe it has to do with the asynchronous nature of the RXJS/custom error handling I'm doing in the `error-logger.service.ts`

Comment: How is your service registered? Is it in a `providers` array in a module? Or in the component?

Comment: Yes, the service is global and registered in the `app.module.ts` providers array.

Comment: Where is logError being called?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the file where 'logError` is being called. `logError` is being called from a global `global-error-handler.service.ts` file, also globally registered in `app.module.ts`. This global-error-handler overrides Angular's default `ErrorHandler`, acting on its behalf to provide custom error handling. Hmm...this has me thinking, maybe my `errorLogger` service is being instantiated in `global-error-handler.service.ts` before the component passes it the new property value...

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax, so hope someone else can jump in. But two possibilities ... 1) somehow that syntax is providing multiple instances of the service. 2) you are losing *this*.

Comment: Thank you! Those are two good clues - I'll look closer tomorrow and update with what I found.

Comment: I've checked and `this` is still registered to the appropriate property. Also, my service should be a singleton since it's provided in AppModule and also has `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})`.
This is a tricky problem - I think it may have to do with the asynchronous nature of some of my RXJS logic on the observable. Hmm..

Comment: It definitely should *not* be provided twice. It should be in the `providers` array of AppModule OR use `providedIn`. Not both.

Comment: Ah, I see. I have `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` because I created the service via Angular CLI, and that line was automatically included. I've tried removing my service from the AppModule providers array, but still have the same problem. I also tried removing `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` - same thing.

In my GlobalErrorHandlerService, I wonder if using `injector` is creating a new instance of the errorLoggerService? `let loggerService = this.injector.get(ErrorLoggerService);`

Answer (score 1):

i think this code gonna work for you:

First 'error-logger.service.ts':

Convert your appName in

```
public appName = new BehaviorSubject<string>('initialName')

logError(error) {
   return appName.pipe(tap(appName => console.log(appName)))
   // or
   //return appName.pipe(switchMap(appName=> {
   //     console.log(appName)
   //     return of('{data}')
   // }))
}
```

Second my-component.component.ts:

```
this.errorLoggerService.appName.next('otherName')
```

Third GlobalErrorHandlerService:

```
loggerService.logError(error)    
  .subscribe(
    appName => console.warn(appName),
    // or data => console.warn(data)
    error => {throw error},
    () => console.log("empty")
  );
```

I my mind works, hope so works :)

Comment: hmm...I've got all of this connected, but am still getting the same initialName value for `appName`.

Comment: Why you don trye to put the ErrorLoggerService in the constructor of the GlobalErrorHandlerService?

Comment: Thanks. I believe I tried that already, but I'll try once more with your code. As a general question, why would all of this new RXJS logic (tap, pipe, etc) be needed in order to update a service's property from a component? Is it because with my old code, the asynchronous nature of RXJS data streams are somehow superseding me setting that property from the component?

Comment: First, the pipe is a property or function that have any observable value, it's used to transform o do things whit the information inside the observabe, in the case of tap, its used to take and use the value inside the observable, thats mean when you suscribe to that BehaviorSubject, you do something whit the value (in my code i print the component name ) and you recibe the same value in the susbcribe function (in the GlobalErrorHandlerService).

Comment: Second, the observable (BehaviorSubject or Subject) have some function to update the value of the observable (like next(), passing the value to the next observer), this give the posibility to update this value in any component only executing that function and the observer that susbcriben that value getting the value when change.